# ORACLE TRIM function

Tags: oracle, trim

suppose a column defined as:

```
col varchar2(5)
```

- If `col='X'` is `true`;
- If `trim(col)=trim('X')` is `true`;
- But if col contains `' '`, then if `trim(col)=trim(' ')` is `false`;

Why?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle *doesn't support empty strings* like **''**; Oracle uses *null* instead (whenever the result should be an *empty string* you'll get *null* in fact). Since

```
  null = null -- <- is null (and not true)
```

Your formula

```
  trim(col) = trim(' ') -- <- equals to "null = null"
```

is null (and not true) too

Comment: `null = null -- <- is always false` - this is definitely not true. `null = null` returns `null`. Try this:

`declare test boolean := null = null;
begin if test is null then raise program_error; end if; end;`. Yes, the idea is the same: condition will not work, but it is not false!